# Wien bridge oscillator LTSPICE

Tags: oscillator, simulation, spice

I am looking for a good oscillator to implement in a circuit. I was trying to simulate a Wien Bridge oscillator in LTSPICE but I have no success as my output is always 0 V. Is there a special parameter of simulation I should use? Here's the schematic I am using:

[image]

Comment: The output is the load R9 of 1k

Comment: You might have to do a pulse input. Real-world oscillations start usually by ambient noise (thermally-generated). In a simulation there is no noise tho.

Comment: Try passing the 'startup' parameter to the simulation (that way, the supplies will ramp until they reach their target value).

It is option *Start external DC supply voltages at 0V* on the *Edit simulation command* dialog box.

Comment: I added a little pulse a the R1 resistor and it works perfectly, thanks for all suggestions

Comment: Another alternative would be to give one of the capacitors an "initial condition" - that means: A tiny voltage at start up.

Comment: Have you got an option in transient analysis to ignore the initial several milli seconds? To prove this try running the transient window for maybe 1 second. Also, if you have the option, set the maximum time step to be sub micro seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question may be solved, I ran into this sort of problem when trying to simulate the Wien bridge oscillator.

### Using LTSPICE:

1. The **voltage gain of the amplifier circuit MUST be equal too or greater than 3 for oscillations to start** because the input is 1/3 of the output. This value, ( Av ≥ 3 ) is set by the feedback resistor network.
2. Since oscillators start up from thermal noise you may need to **provide an initial pulse input** for the simulation to get going.

The following steps enabled me to successfully simulate this oscillator *without* an initial pulse input on Proteus Software.

### Using Proteus:

1. Step 1 above applies.
2. **Proteus simulation software does not require this initial 'push'** and thus it may be easier to use Proteus software.
3. Make sure to use active capacitors while simulating, otherwise nothing will happen.