# 89 Hz Wien bridge oscillator output signal does not appear

Tags: simulation, oscilloscope, output

[image]

The circuit is designed to generate 89 Hz, but in this case, the sine wave does not appear.

Comment: Your Scope Channel A is at 5kV/div. Is that really the amplitude of the signal you are expecting?

Comment: the title of you post does not match the content of your post ... please change one ... you also did not ask a question that could be answered

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106686/wien-bridge-oscillator-ltspice/348342#348342

Answer (score 1):

I believe Wien bridge oscillators need a theoretical minimum gain of 3 to sustain oscillations at a constant amplitude and, at start-up, you might need something like a gain of 4 or 5 to initiate oscillation. Try a higher gain is my advice - make R4 more like 20 kohm and see if it starts.

Next is to add amplitude control to keep the sinewave all pretty. Then get rid of the dinosaur 741 op-amp in favour of a much better device.

Comment: it produces squarewave

Comment: So try moving the gain to 4 then 3.5 etc. and you should see it start to become a sinewave. Also note the final part of my answer about amplitude control. This sort of oscillator does not produce a sinewave without another level of sophistication aka an amplitude control circuit.

Comment: It worked, thank you

Comment: @AhmadAlhayashi do you know what to do now in terms of this site's etiquette?